# How to run Selenium tests against local code?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, pipeline, specflow

I am using Specflow, Selenium in my current project. When I want to run my test cases I start my current project and then in my Appsetting json file I have set url like

```
"baseURL": {
 "url": "http://localhost:5000/mypage.aspx"
}
```

So everytime I need to run my tests, first I need to run my server. I can't run my tests in Pipeline because the URL will be different. Is there any way that my project run the server automatically and then get the url of the server so the tests point to the current branch url?

Comment: The typical way of doing this is to create a new app in IIS running on your machine. The folder containing the app in IIS can point to the folder for your web application.

Comment: You can tie Selenium in to the IDE debugger's launch of the browser.  You just set Selenium to use the same port.  Also note that Selenium itself also uses "localhost", so if you find problems there, you should try navigating with the ip instead... 127.0.0.1... (some of those problems can be related to HOSTS file settings..)